# Setting device name in serenity.properties file for chrome driver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

How do I set the mobile emulation for Nexus 5 view in Serenity managed chrome driver?

I tried going through this link:
https://johnfergusonsmart.com/configuring-chromedriver-easily-with-serenity-bdd/

Which explain setting preferences for chrome.

```
Chrome preferences
You can also provide more advanced options using the setExperimentalOption() method:

Map<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downLoadDirectory);
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("pdfjs.disabled", true);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);

In Serenity, you would pass these using properties prefixed with the chrome_preferences prefix, e.g.

chrome_preferences.download.default_directory = /my/download/directory
chrome_preferences.profile_default_content_settings.popups = 0
chrome_preferences.pdfjs.disabled=true
```

From this, I tried setting the mobileEmulation as

`chrome.capabilities.mobile_emulation.device_name= Google Nexus 5`
`chrome.options.mobileEmulation.deviceName= Google Nexus 5`

and a few other logical variants, but none of them succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found to help me in this issue it to create a custom WebDriver.

I had to create a class which extends DriverSource. And then link it to the Serenity Properties file. This will give me the driver I need.

http://www.thucydides.info/docs/serenity/#_custom_webdriver_implementations

> You can add your own custom WebDriver provider by implementing the
>   DriverSource interface. First, you need to set up the following system
>   properties (e.g. in your serenity.properties file):
>
> ```
> webdriver.driver = provided
> webdriver.provided.type = mydriver
> webdriver.provided.mydriver = com.acme.MyPhantomJSDriver
> thucydides.driver.capabilities = mydriver
> ```
>
> Your custom driver must implement the DriverSource interface, as shown
>   here:
>
> ```
> public class MyPhantomJSDriver implements DriverSource {
>
>     @Override
>     public WebDriver newDriver() {
>         try {
>             DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
>             // Add
>             return new PhantomJSDriver(ResolvingPhantomJSDriverService.createDefaultService(),
> ```
>
> capabilities);
>               }
>               catch (IOException e) {
>                   throw new Error(e);
>               }
>           }
>
> ```
>         @Override
>     public boolean takesScreenshots() {
>         return true;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This driver will now take screenshots normally.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, able to launch the Chrome browser but it's asking to log in to the google account, so manually I have logged in to the google account but when I start the execution I am still getting the loogin page, is there any way to skip this page?